# Using Match and Max formula to get the last value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This Excel formula below can return the last value in row 1. I wonder how does it work. Especially, I don't understand the purpose of using `MATCH(MAX(1:1),1:1,1)-1` in the formula.

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH(MAX(1:1),1:1,1)-1)
```

Comment: I'm sure someone can comment on this better in "english", but to see how the formula resolves, step by step, in the formula bar, click the "Evaluate Formula" text under "Formulas".  This will show you how the function works, "piece by piece".

Answer (score 1):

That formula does not seem to be reliable.  With this data:

> 1|2|3|  |9|8|6|   |17|6|4|10|1

that formula returns 17.  Also, it does not work with text.

I suggest:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN(1:1)>0),1:1)
```

which will work with text or numbers.  See HELP for LOOKUP to understand how it works if `lookup_value` is greater than any item in the array being searched.

Answer (score 1):

Put `=MATCH(MAX(1:1),1:1,1)` into a cell (not on the first row) and type some numbers into random cells in the first row. The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) will return the column index number (e.g. column B is 2, column Z is 26, etc).

You are using the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) to shift from A1 so it has to be 1 less than the actual column index number, hence -1.

A better formula to locate the last number or date in row 1 would be,

```
=index(1:1, 1, match(1e99, 1:1))
```

[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is considered volatile¹; the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) is not.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>